# Simple LINQ to SQL extension method

Tags: linq-to-sql, extension-methods, criteria

How would I write a simple LINQ to SQL extension method called "IsActive" which would contain a few basic criteria checks of a few different fields, so that I could reuse this "IsActive" logic all over the place without duplicating the logic.

For example, I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
return db.Listings.Where(x => x.IsActive())
```

And IsActive would be something like:

```
public bool IsActive(Listing SomeListing)
{
    if(SomeListing.Approved==true && SomeListing.Deleted==false)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Otherwise, I am going to have to duplicate the same old where criteria in a million different queries right throughout my system.

Note: method must render in SQL..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a partial class to achieve this.

In a new file place the following:

```
namespace Namespace.Of.Your.Linq.Classes 
{
    public partial class Listing 
    {
        public bool IsActive()
        {
            if(this.Approved==true && this.Deleted==false)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Since the Listing object (x in your lambda) is just an object, and Linq to SQL defines the generated classes as partial, you can add functionality (properties, methods, etc) to the generated classes using partial classes.

I don't believe the above will be rendered into the SQL query.  If you want to do all the logic in the SQL Query, I would recommend making a method that calls the where method and just calling that when necessary.

**EDIT**

Example:

```
public static class DataManager
{
    public static IEnumerable<Listing> GetActiveListings()
    {
        using (MyLinqToSqlDataContext ctx = new MyLinqToSqlDataContext())
        {
            return ctx.Listings.Where(x => x.Approved && !x.Deleted);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, whenever you want to get all the Active Listings, just call `DataManager.GetActiveListings()`

Comment: Cool. Thanks. Will this translate to SQL ok?

Comment: Kyle, my example above is querying the db directly, i.e. return db.Where (I didn't have ToList()), therefore its important that it can be translated to SQL as I won't be working with local objects. Can you outline how to achieve your second suggestion of making the method that calls the Where method? Thanks again.

Comment: Added an example to my answer. Basically, create a method that returns the active listings that you are looking for.

Comment: Great, thanks Kyle. I went with something along these lines and it does work great. I read that LINQ to SQL tries to optimise everything into a single SQL query at runtime, so even if you run your results through a number of these kind of "criteria filter" methods, it should turn out ok in the end performance wise.. *touch wood*

Comment: Something I found out the hard way: If the Linq extension method returns `IEnumerable<T>`, then it won't be translated into the SQL. If the Linq extension method returns `IQueryable<T>`, it will be. Keep this in mind, and you might want to change the return type of the method in my example to reflect this. The Linq to SQL runtime runs the query against the database when the `IQueryable<T>` is converted to `IEnumerable<T>` or an individual object (through `.ToArray()`, `.Single()`, `.Cast()` etc.)

Answer (score 5):

Good question, there is a clear need to be able to define a **re-useable** filtering expression to avoid redundantly specifying logic in disparate queries.

This method will generate a filter you can pass to the Where method.

```
public Expression<Func<Listing, bool>> GetActiveFilter()
{
  return someListing => someListing.Approved && !someListing.Deleted;
}
```

Then later, call it by:

```
Expression<Func<Filter, bool>> filter = GetActiveFilter()
return db.Listings.Where(filter);
```

Since an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` is used, there will be no problem translating to sql.

---

Here's an extra way to do this:

```
public static IQueryable<Filter> FilterToActive(this IQueryable<Filter> source)
{
  var filter = GetActiveFilter()
  return source.Where(filter);
}
```

Then later,

```
return db.Listings.FilterToActive();
```

Comment: Interesting.  I wasn't aware of the `Expression<TDelegate>` class.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
  public static bool IsActive( this Listing SomeListing)
  {
    if(SomeListing.Approved==true && SomeListing.Deleted==false)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, looks clean. Will this translate to SQL ok?

Comment: A partial class would be more appropriate in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party here, but yet another way to do it that I use is:

```
public static IQueryable<Listing> GetActiveListings(IQueryable<Listing> listings)
{
    return listings.Where(x => x.Approved && !x.Deleted);
}
```

and then

```
var activeListings = GetActiveListings(ctx.Listings);
```